# HAML: table column's width not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, haml, markup

Nothing from this not working. When I typing large text table going deep right and horizontal nav appears.

**index.haml**

```
%table{:border => 1, :width => "100%"}
  %tr
    %th{:width => "200"} Name
    %th.edit Edit

  - @wallpapers.each do |wallpaper|
    %tr
      %td.name= wallpaper.name
      %td= link_to (image_tag wallpaper.thumb.url(:thumb)), edit_wallpaper_path(wallpaper)
      %td= button_to 'Delete', wallpaper_path(wallpaper), :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this wallpaper?', :method => :delete
```

**style.css**

```
th.edit {width:20%;}
td.name {width:20%;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really want to set the style, not html attributes

Try this:

```
%table{:style=>"border: 1px; width: 100%"}
```

What you're actually creating is:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
```

And you should be creating:

```
<table style="border: 1px; width: 100%">
```

of course, using classes and CSS would be better, but this will solve immediate concern.

Comment: it's because I used such thing __%table.classname{:cellpadding=>5,:cellspacing=>5,:border=>'1'}__. As u know cellpadding and cellspacing are not CSS part.
But anyway your solution not works for me :( Table columns is still wide-wide. I made
**%th{ :style => "width:200px"; } Name** and nothing.

Comment: this is the correct way to do it in Haml. your problems are now in CSS.

Comment: so newbie mistake :( I have test-text such as "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..." without any spaces. And because of it horizontal nav appeaps. Thanks Jesse! :)